# Java String Split using RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a string using Regex and I want to use that regex in java. The below regex is partially working but it is not including curly braces.

```
String to Split: /opt/app/{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}/{/Xpath/sub/tree}/Archive
RegEx: {(.*?)}
Expected Output: 
/opt/app/
{YYYY}
{MM}
{DD}
{/Xpath/sub/tree}
/Archive
```

The idea here is I want to replace the data between {} and construct the string back. I am open to any other suggestions as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes @MaxZoom. I opted for RegEx and do the string replacement and concatenate the strings back. I have a java version limitation otherwise I could have used String.join as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split using this regex:

```
/(?=\{)|(?<=})/
```

In Java:

```
String[] arr = input.split("/(?=\\{)|(?<=})/");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gix3c5/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `/` - Match literal `/`
- `(?=\{)` - Lookahead to assert next character is {
- `|` - OR
- `(?<=})` - Lookbehind to assert previous character is }
- `/` - Match literal `/`

Comment: Case of a serial down voting

Comment: @SirishReddy: Did this work out?

Comment: Thank you @anubhava. It worked and I got my desired output.